# Setting the body class by a page ancestor

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I know how to set the body class dynamically using the current page `uid`:

```
page.bodyTagCObject = HTML
page.bodyTagCObject.value.field = uid
page.bodyTagCObject.value.wrap = <body id="uid|">
```

But how can I set the body class using the id of the top-level ancestor of a page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one:

```
page.bodyTagCObject = HTML
page.bodyTagCObject.value.dataWrap = <body id="uid{leveluid:0}">
```

You can read about way of getting such data here:
http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.7.0/view/2/2/

Find text "getText"